# How to make executable file independent from the project directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

To make Executable Python, we do:

Step 1: place `#!/usr/local/bin/python` at the top

Step 2: `chmod +x <file_name>.py`

Step 3: `./<file_name>.py <parameters-optional>`

But In this case, I still need to carry out the project folder with all dependencies (i.e., other python scripts that are imported). How can I create an executable file that can be placed anywhere without having to copy the entire project directory? My project involves 10 python files but one of them is the main program that I want to make it sort of portable so that I don't have to carry the entire project folder.

Thank you

Comment: If you just want to make the script accessible elsewhere on your own machine you can make a symbolic link to the main program, using the `ln` command. Eg, if `/home/some_path` is a location in your `PATH` where you want to place the script, do `cd /home/some_path; ln -s full_path_to_script.py target_name.py`, and then you can run the script from anywhere with `target_name.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the environment variable 'PATH' to point to the program directory

```
PATH="/home/username/path/to/your/main_program/:$PATH"
```

Comment: In where I put this path?

Comment: @Alonso Put it in your  ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login

Comment: @Alonso The PATH environment variable can be adjusted in your `~/.bashrc` file, you probably already have an entry there. The default PATH is created in `/etc/profile`, and there may be PATH-related stuff in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Also check the files Susan mentioned. There should be something like `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` and `export PATH` in an `/etc/` profile file. The definition & the `export` may be combined into one line, that's the usual practice in the `.bashrc` file. You normally should _not_ modify the files in `/etc/`, unless you know what you're doing.